# Vectorize this for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have this for loop that I need to vectorize. The code below works, but takes a lot of time (this is a simplified example, the full version will have about 1e6 rows in col_ids). Can someone give me an idea how to vectorize this code to get rid of the loop? If it matters, the `col_ids` are fixed (will be the same every time the code is run), while the `values` will change.

```
values = np.array([1.5, 2, 2.3])
col_ids = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1]])
result = np.zeros((4,3))
for idx, col_idx in enumerate(col_ids):
    result[np.arange(4),col_idx] += values[idx]
```

Result:

```
[[5.8 0.  0. ]
 [5.8 0.  0. ]
 [3.5 2.3 0. ]
 [1.5 4.3 0. ]]
```

**Update**:
I am adding a second example as there was some ambiguity in the dimensions of my first example. Only `values` and `col_ids` are updated, everything else as in first example. (I keep the first one, since this is referred to in the answers)

```
values = np.array([1.5, 2, 5, 20, 50])
col_ids = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1], [0,0,1,2], [0,1,2,2]])
```

Result:

```
[[78.5  0.   0. ]
 [28.5 50.   0. ]
 [ 3.5 25.  50. ]
 [ 1.5  7.  70. ]]
```

So `result` is m x n, `col_ids` is k x m and values has length k. Both m and n are small (m=4, n=3), k is large (about 1e6 in full example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorize the loop, but creating an additional intermediate array is much slower for larger data (starting from *result* with shape `(50,50)`)

```py
import numpy as np

values = np.array([1.5, 2, 2.3])
col_ids = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1]])

(np.equal.outer(col_ids, np.arange(len(values))) * values[:,None,None]).sum(0)

# for a fixed result shape (4,3)
# (np.equal.outer(col_ids, np.arange(3)) * values[:,None,None]).sum(0)
```

Output

```
array([[5.8, 0. , 0. ],
       [5.8, 0. , 0. ],
       [3.5, 2.3, 0. ],
       [1.5, 4.3, 0. ]])
```

The only reliably faster solution I could find is `numba` (using `version 0.55.1`). I thought this implementation would benefit from parallel execution, but I couldn't get any speed up on a 2-core colab instance.

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=False) # Try parallel=True for multi-threaded execution, no speed up in my benchmarks 
def fill(val, ids):
    res = np.zeros(ids.shape[::-1])
    for i in nb.prange(len(res)):
        for j in range(res.shape[1]):
            res[i, ids[j,i]] += val[j]
    return res

fill(values, col_ids)
```

Output

```
array([[5.8, 0. , 0. ],
       [5.8, 0. , 0. ],
       [3.5, 2.3, 0. ],
       [1.5, 4.3, 0. ]])
```

---

For a fixed *result* shape `(4,3)` with suitable input.

```
@nb.njit(boundscheck=True) # ~1.25x slower, but much safer
def fill(val, ids):
    res = np.zeros((4,3))
    for i in nb.prange(ids.shape[0]):              
        for j in range(ids.shape[1]):   
            res[j, ids[i,j]] += val[i]
    return res

fill(values, col_ids)
```

Output for the updated example data

```
array([[78.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [28.5, 50. ,  0. ],
       [ 3.5, 25. , 50. ],
       [ 1.5,  7. , 70. ]])
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried to hold back this time so as not to use Numba :p . A parallel implementation will not be faster here because of *false sharing* assuming `len(res)` is small and `col_ids` is big. In fact, this should cause the thread execution to be mostly sentimentalized due to an effect called cache-line bouncing. An efficient solution is to accumulate results in a temporary thread-local array instead and only write the value back in the original array at the end. This is unfortunately pretty cumbersome to do in Numba though...

Comment: I realize now that I should have provided more information about the dimensions of the arrays. The question is updated

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I implemented it, and notice that the result dimension increases when the number of rows in col_ids increases.  In my problem, the result dimension has a fixed number of 3 columns...

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I have added a second example to my question, and have also added info on the dimensions of the variables

Comment: Surprisingly, the implementation for a fixed *result* shape over your expected axes is significantly different in `numba`. I added a solution for both approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using `np.add.at`. However, AFAIK, this function does not support 2D array so you need to flatten the arrays, computing the 1D flatten indices, and then call the function:

```py
n, m = result.shape
result = np.zeros((4,3))
indices = np.tile(np.arange(0, n*m, m), col_ids.shape[0]) + col_ids.ravel()
np.add.at(result.ravel(), indices, np.repeat(values, n)) # In-place
print(result)
```

Comment: 2D arrays are supported `np.add.at(result, (np.arange(col_ids.size) % result.shape[0], col_ids.ravel()), values.repeat(result.shape[0]))`, but it is really slow for larger arrays.